# Shared workbook copy/move delete p_roblem?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Hi I've a shared workbook. But it doesn't allow me copy/move or delete sheet(s). How can I solve this problem? Or How can I undo sharing? (I don't remember how I Shared :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to change the permission for the workbook folder.check if the workbook has a Protection area where you can change permissions from within the workbook. another would be to check the permissions that are allowed in the file itself IE right click and go to sharing and security then set the permisions for EVERYONE for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Review, then "Share Workbook".  A window will pop up with two tabs, under "Editing" uncheck the box marked "Allow changes by more than one user at a the same time.  This also allows workbook merging"

Answer (score 0):

None of the above things worked for me, I am not the original creator of the shared XLS file I am working on though. If you uncheck the box marked "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time" even when you share the workbook again other users will be unable to save their changes, so that wont' work for me either.

**What DID work was:**

1. Select the entire worksheet you want to copy (*by clicking in the top left corner between row A & column 1*).
2. In a new blank worksheet Paste > Formatting (*this pastes only the formatting, no text or numbers*).
3. Go back to original worksheet, select the columns, and Copy.
4. Paste (*just regular paste*) them into the new tab by selecting the columns in the new tab before you click Paste.

This copied everything perfectly for me.  Hope this helps!!!